# How do I get the auto ID of an unsaved database entity in EF4.5 MVC / Displaying tables of child objects during parent creating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, razor

I am struggling with a situation where I am creating a parent object and child object both at the same time. *Ideally I would like to create the parent inside a single form, and from that form be able to add child nodes in a **table format***. The issue arises as I try to add the child node to a collection in the parent object, while the parent itself not yet has been created.

Simplified, the program code looks something like this:

**Parent Creation form HTML5 Razor:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm))
{
   <table>
       <tr>
           <th>Child header</th>
       </tr>
       @if (ViewBag.Children_list != null)
       {
           foreach (var item in (ViewBag.Children_list as List<Child>))
           {
           <tr>
               <td>@item.Child_name</td>
               <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete child" , "DeleteParentSection", "Partial", new { ChildType = Defs.Child, ChildID = item.ID}, null)</td>
           </tr>
           }
       } 
   </table>
   <p>
      @Html.ActionLink("Add Child", "CreateParentSection", "Partial", new { ParentID = Model.ParentID, ChildType = Defs.Child}, null)
   </p>
}
```

The two referenced **controllers** look like this:

```
 public ActionResult CreateParentSection(int ParentID , int ChildType)
 {
     Parent parent = db.Parents.Find(ParentID);

     switch (ChildType)
     {
         case Defs.Child:
             Child child= new Child();
             Parent.Children.Add(child);
             break;
         case Defs.AnotherChild:
             (...)
     }

     db.SaveChanges();
     return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
 }
```

And:

```
public ActionResult DeleteParentSection(int ChildType, int ChildID)
{
    switch (ChildType)
    {
        case Defs.Child:
            Child child = db.AllChildren.Find(ChildID);
            db.AllChildren.Remove(child);
            break;
        case Defs.AnotherChild:
            (...)
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```

When the program tries to find the active Parent object from its ParentID in the *CreateParentSection* action, no parent is found, as the parent still has not been saved.

I believe it would be possible to save the Parent object before I allow the user to add children, but this seems like an unwanted solution in my opinion, as I like to keep a clean design pattern, and it would break clutter the code for input validation.

Does anyone know a clean way so solve this kind of problem?